# Twitter Typeahead Bootstrap Conflict

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I already manage to run the Twitter Typeahead 
But one thing is wrong there is a white box that keeps apearing and it becomes transparent 

here is my code

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead form-control input-lg" placeholder="Renovation, Plumming, Welder, Carpent, Driver , Cleaner Etc...">
```

What I encountered error

[image]

What I need
[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control input-lg" placeholder="Renovation, Plumming, Welder, Carpent, Driver , Cleaner Etc...">
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.form-group {
  width: // discover this
  height: // discover this
}
div.form-group input.form-control {
  width: // discover this
  height: // discover this
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: My main main problem is how can I get rid of that white box inside the input text.

Comment: if I understood, you have to change `background-color` of `input`.  I edited my answer

Comment: Can I just use the given Height and Width of Bootstrap in "form-control input-lg" instead of discovering them ?